# Automating button presses

Tags: arduino, switches, components, mechanical

I'm working on a project which involves automating the pressing of some buttons on a device. There are five push buttons, which are quite stiff and require fast repetitive presses - around about ~7Hz with 50% duty cycle. I also have one toggle switch that needs to be switched at a rate of ~10Hz.

My first thought was to use servos, but the ones I have seem to be too slow and weak for the push buttons. They don't quite get the speed I need for the toggle switch, either. I don't want to spend a fortune on expensive servos, so I figured there might be an alternate method using cheap motors and a rack-and-pinion setup. The idea would be to have one fast servo for the toggle, and a bunch of cheap motors with a vertical rack to press the buttons.

Are there any alternatives to this approach? Am I missing any obvious methods to automate this?

Comment: Is there a reason that you couldn't replace the buttons with relay contacts, optoisolators, etc?

Comment: @DeanB I can't modify the device in any way (warranty issues!)

Comment: Sounds like a paradox.  If you actuate the buttons and switches mechanically at 7-10Hz, you'll almost certainly need the warranty at some point.  If you modify the device to emulate button presses, you void the warranty but may not need one...

Comment: @DeanB These buttons are designed to take some beating. The front panels are Lexan plastic and the buttons are rated at up to ~35M presses. Each batch of inputs is likely to take around 5 minutes, so even at 10Hz solid that's 3000 presses. In reality it's likely to be less than half that, since only 2 or 3 buttons are used per input section. That's *at least* 10,000 batches before any of the buttons fail.

Comment: My friend did similar when working in the testing lab at KFC.  Get a bigger motor, use leverage, and beat the hell out of them.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I sincerely hope you're not talking about live chickens...

Comment: lol, he was testing that oven doors lasted a zillion openings, as per the manufacturer's claims.  Also, he'd squirt hot oil on membrane control panels, etc.  The machines would run for days.

Comment: @TonyEnnis It honestly didn't occur to me that you could be talking about mechanical equipment! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an electronics answer, since you can't modify the device to simply replicate the button and switch contact closures electrically.

This sounds like consumer products testing to me.  You may want to look at what consumer product test houses do to automate the actuation of devices without modifying them.

For your application, I would suggest one of two approaches:

- Solenoids.  Use direct acting, spring return solenoids for the button presses.  The spring rate will determine the maximum actuation frequency.  If you can tune it for resonance, you can reduce current requirements.  For the toggle, use two opposing solenoids with series springs - i.e. actuate the toggle through the spring such that you limit the maximum force on the lever and don't have to constantly adjust the assembly.
- Pneumatics.  If you've got compressed air available, going with pneumatic acutation will allow you to actuate each point elastically (air is compressable, so pneumatic actuators have inherent compliance) and with controllable force (vary the air pressure).  This would mean that you could use a much smaller power supply, as you'd be driving small solenoid valves rather than potentially large plunger solenoids.

Sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: *\*facepalm\** - I have no idea why I didn't think of solenoids.

Comment: I'll second the pneumatic approach.